# VS2010 live debugging exe

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, debugging, executable

I have a large 'c' based project that I have using visual studio 2010. Environment variables are pointed to the debug folder for the resulting executables that are produced, using the debug release. How can I debug the executables if they are called from the command line?

More specifically what is happening is I have a python script calling perl scripts that call different executables... The c code runs for a bit (it creates a log), but it eventually just stops/crashes, then asks me if I want to debug. When VS opens I don't get any source code or much useful information. I would love to know how I can get the executable to stop at a break point so I can step through the code.

Comment: Put __debugbreak() in your code temporarily to invoke the just-in-time debugger.  Or use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: __debugbreak() doesn't seem to bring it up. :( That link looks promising. I'll give it a go.

Comment: I've also tried the link you gave me. Doing this (including the debugbreak lines) still seems to only call the bugger after it has already crashed.

Also the debugger doesn't seem to get source code. Only assembly.

Comment: I got annoyed and just decided to put in all the intended arguments and debug right from the solution. Still though I'd like to know what's going on.